# How to display a correctly rotated Preview in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

We use Flutter to make camera apps for Android and iOS.

```
camera: ^0.10.0+4
path_provider: ^2.0.11
path: ^1.8.2
```

```
CameraController cc = CameraController(
    firstCamera,
    ResolutionPreset.max,
    imageFormatGroup:
        Platform.isIOS ? ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888 : ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
);
await cc.initialize();
```

```
Center(child: CameraPreview(cc)),
```

In this case, Android will have an animation that switches between portrait and landscape, but it works as we expect, and we can also eliminate the animation by adding the following.

However, if the iPhone is upside down (portraitDown), the preview will be displayed horizontally, as in landscape.

We worked around the problem on iOS by using [Native Device Orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation) to rotate the preview. However, this method is not beautiful because it delays the rotation of the preview.

Can we display previews more simply and beautifully?

This question does not include how to rotate a captured image.

[image]

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.6, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.3.6 on channel stable at /Users/xxxx/fvm/versions/stable
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 6928314d50 (5 weeks ago), 2022-10-25 16:34:41 -0400
    • Engine revision 3ad69d7be3
    • Dart version 2.18.2
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/xxxx/src/android-sdks
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14B47b
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.52.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone SE2 MS (mobile) • XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX • ios            • iOS 16.1.1 20B101
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                     • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.110

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Comment: Have you tried checking "Upside down" orientation? You can open ios/Runner.xcworkspace in xcode and Click on "Runner" then select Targets "Runner" and scroll down to "Deployment Info"

Comment: I forgot to mention it but of course we have already tried it . You will be able to try it.